# xamarin fill image without setting height or weight

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, image-resizing

How can I display responsive image without setting height or width?

below code doesn't display any image bc i am not setting height

```
 <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="10">
                <yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>
                    <yummy:DropShadow Color="#000000" Offset="10,10"   />
                </yummy:PancakeView.Shadow>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ff:CachedImage x:Name="ImageURLFront" Source="images.png"
                                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                        Aspect="AspectFill" />
                </Grid>
            </yummy:PancakeView>
```

Comment: I used your code to successfully display the image, did you miss the cacheImage initialization ?

Comment: yeah super weird, my code works fine only if i use `heightOption`

Comment: Try wrapping them in a StackLayout.